# Visual editor didn't break line when show front-end in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I built plugin in Wordpress for write question under tool visual editor, but when get data response to front-end content didn't break line.

PHP code below:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', esc_attr($item['question'])); ?>
```

[Photo data display front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huqtS.png)

How to solve that on front-end.

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the place of

esc_attr($item['question'])

use 
$item['question']

Because esc_attr function remove html attirbutes. like line break h1 tags extra
for more information please visit.
[link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/)

hope it will help you.:)